# como traducir caracteres latinos a entidades Html usando flask

Tags: html, python, python-2.7, flask

Estoy usando Flask, para capturar un texto con un formulario Html.
En el formulario le he puesto el `acept-encoding=ISO-8859-1`.
Pero cuando en el formulario tecleo una eñe minuscula, resulta que a través del POST del formuario, me llega un UNICODE, con ordinal 65533.
Y claro, no se, en que codificación me está devolviendo esta eñe
Ya que si en python hago `letra=u'ñ'`, si que me devuelve el código de la eñe en ISO-8859-1 y lo se traducir a una entidad html, que sería `&ntilde;`

Así que no se si es que el POST, no lleva el encoding adecuado, que no se si se puede forzar de alguna forma. O es que el Flask internamente hace alguna traducción. ¿Alguien sabe que como traducirlo a entidades html o traducirlo a la codificación estandar de latin1?

Comment: He buscado este codigo de caracter 65533 en la tabla unicode y se corresponde con "replacement char". Es el caracter que se pone cuando no se puede representar graficamente un caracter. Entonces...como configuro el servidor de desarrollo de flask, para que funcione con ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 0):

**Nota**. Esta respuesta quizás debería ser un comentario, pero era demasiado larga. La editaré y mejoraré si recibo más información según detallo más abajo.

Faltan datos para una respuesta definitiva, pero de momento veo lo siguiente:

- La cabecera `accept-encoding` no está relacionada con la codificación de los caracteres, sino con la codificación de los *bytes* y básicamente sirve para especificar si admites que vengan comprimidos o no, y con qué formato de compresión. Es irrelevante con respecto a tu problema.
- Flask traduce automáticamente a Unicode lo que recibe del navegador y para saber qué tabla de códigos ha de usar, mirará la cabecera `Content-Type:` que el navegador le haya enviado. Sospecho por tanto que esa cabecera es la que está mal. Prueba a imprimirla desde flask (`print(request.headers)`).
- ¿Y cómo elige el navegador qué *encoding* usar? Usará el que el servidor indique a través de una cabecera `<meta>` en el HTML. A falta de esta información usará un valor por defecto, que puede depender del operativo. Creo que quizás lo que te falta es poner en la cabecera de tu HTML (el que contiene el form) la etiqueta `<meta charset="iso-8859-1">`.

Con esta información que te acabo de dar puedes hacer algunas pruebas más. Informa de tus resultados para poder adaptar esta respuesta convenientemente.